# django-embed-video wagtail can not display saved videos

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am trying to display the Embed saved videos on my homepage, but for some reason only the `object` class divs are created,the image itself with its title don't show up. 
This is my `models.py`

```
class HomePage(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
        # InlinePanel('home_images', label="Gallery images"),
        InlinePanel('video')
    ]
class VideoBasedModel(models.Model):
    page = ParentalKey(HomePage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='video')
    video = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtail_embed_videos.EmbedVideo',
        verbose_name="Video",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
    )
    panels = [
        EmbedVideoChooserPanel('video')
    ]
    template_name = 'home/homepage.html'
```

and this is my home_page.html

```
{% block list %}
       <div class="lists">
                <div>  <!-- List Nunti -->
                    <div class="title">
                        <hr />
                        <h3>Nunti</h3>
                        <hr />
                    </div>
                    {% for item in page.video.all %}
                        <div class = 'object'>
                            {% video item.video 'small' %}
                        </div>

                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Am I missing something, does django-embed-video have a default template where the code for the embed videos need to go?

Comment: Have you included `{% load embed_video_tags %}` on your template (as per the docs: https://github.com/infoportugal/wagtail-embedvideos#quick-start)?

Comment: Yes, I included them